# Schwartz Value Survey (SVS)

Tags: measurement

I am looking for the Schwartz Value Survey (SVS; Schwartz, 1992). I seem to have found a copy [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0065260108602816) in the appendix of this paper but I'm not quite sure if it is okay to use it the way it is presented, or if I need permission to use this scale in my research. I would appreciate any help; thanks in advance.

Comment: The questionnaire has evolved a lot since 1992. Are you sure you want to specifically use the 1992 or a later version? The latest iteration from what I can find is on this site - https://www.thevaluesproject.com/about/

Comment: @Poidah Right, I came across a later version of this survey and decided to use it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Remember that you can always answer your own question, @tacendus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first Schwartz Value Survey (SVS) was published in 1992 which consisted of 56 items. Since then, it has gone through a couple changes. A current version employs 57 items. The SVS56 and SVS57 are different, with one item changed and one item added in the SVS57. Schwartz & Sagiv (1995) is the first article using the SVS57.

A 'face' item was added in 2004, the final survey consisting of 58 items.

The SVS57 is available [here](https://www.mededportal.org/publication/10002/) with a short scoring key included as well. However, I recommend going through the full manual with additional resources, available [here](http://crossculturalcentre.homestead.com/DraftManual_SVS_14Feb2009.doc).